# Visual Studio 2012 LocalDB

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

Does Visual Studio 2012 install package includes SQL Server Express 2012 LocalDB or it has to be installed separately?
If it is separate installation which package should be installed first ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes with VS 2012 (specifically with the SSDT part, as long as you didn't deselect it in the advanced options during installation).  If you did, just install SSDT and it will install localdb.